# java: How to set all text in one line

Tags: java

The output of the `selenium` element is

```
res = webDriverService.getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='main_content']/div/div[2]/h2/span")).get(0).getText();
```

The result of `res` is a string like this:

```
A relationship
A play partner
Friendship
Events
```

I am wondering how can i set all them in one line like

```
A relationship,A play partner,Friendship,Events
```

so, how can i do this?

Comment: what is wrong in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is replace the newline characters with `,` using string manipulation:

```
System.out.println(res.replace("\n",","));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the newlines? Something like this:

```
res = res.replace("\n",",").replace("\r","");
```

Comment: what does `.replace("\r","")` do?

Comment: In case the String uses the windows scheme that terminates each line with a "\r\n" instead of simply "\n"